# How to match, replace and sum header rows from another dataset in R?

Tags: r, merge, matching

I have two data-sets:

a. A data frame that looks like this:

```
        SpeciesA  SpeciesB  SpeciesC  SpeciesD  SpeciesE  SpeciesF
Site1     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site2     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site3     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site4     1          0        4        6          2        5
```

(Note: The row values are NOT identical. This is just for the purpose of representation here)

b. Another data-set that looks like this:

```
Family          Species
Family1         SpeciesA
Family1         SpeciesB
Family1         SpeciesC
Family2         SpeciesD
Family3         SpeciesE
Family4         SpeciesF
```

I want to match the Family column in data-set (2) to the corresponding Species in data-frame(1) and add up the values (if there are multiple species) under the same Family. I know I can use the  `merge` function, but I don't know how to use it, or how to call it in the header row and then sum it all.

Pre-Final output

```
         Family1    Family1   Family1  Family2  Family3  Family4
Site1     1          0        4        6          2        5 
Site2     1          0        4        6          2        5 
Site3     1          0        4        6          2        5 
Site5     1          0        4        6          2        5
```

Final output

```
         Family1      Family2    Family3   Family4
Site1     5             6          2        5           
Site2     5             6          2        5             
Site3     5             6          2        5             
Site4     5             6          2        5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can reshape your first `data.frame` from "wide" to "long" format, `merge` it with the second `data.frame`, and recast the result to wide format, using appropriate aggregation:

```
dfa$id <- row.names(dfa)
mdfa <- reshape2::melt(dfa, id.vars = "id", variable.name = "Species")

reshape2::dcast(
    merge(dfb, mdfa, by = "Species"), 
    id ~ Family, 
    fun.aggregate = sum
)
#      id Family1 Family2 Family3 Family4
# 1 Site1       5       6       2       5
# 2 Site2       5       6       2       5
# 3 Site3       5       6       2       5
# 4 Site4       5       6       2       5
```

---

**Data:**

```
dfa <- read.table(text = "SpeciesA  SpeciesB  SpeciesC  SpeciesD  SpeciesE  SpeciesF
Site1     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site2     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site3     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site4     1          0        4        6          2        5",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfb <- read.table(text = "Family          Species
Family1         SpeciesA
Family1         SpeciesB
Family1         SpeciesC
Family2         SpeciesD
Family3         SpeciesE
Family4         SpeciesF",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
transform(dfa, Family1=SpeciesA+SpeciesB+SpeciesC, Family2=SpeciesD, Family3=SpeciesE, Family4=SpeciesF)[-(1:6)]
```

Here is the result:

```
dfa <- read.table(text = "SpeciesA  SpeciesB  SpeciesC  SpeciesD  SpeciesE  SpeciesF
Site1     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site2     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site3     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site4     1          0        4        6          2        5",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# > transform(dfa, Family1=SpeciesA+SpeciesB+SpeciesC, Family2=SpeciesD, Family3=SpeciesE, Family4=SpeciesF)[-(1:6)]
#       Family1 Family2 Family3 Family4
# Site1       5       6       2       5
# Site2       5       6       2       5
# Site3       5       6       2       5
# Site4       5       6       2       5
```

or you can do a matrix multiplication:

```
as.matrix(dfa) %*% matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1), 6)
# > as.matrix(dfa) %*% matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1), 6)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# Site1    5    6    2    5
# Site2    5    6    2    5
# Site3    5    6    2    5
# Site4    5    6    2    5
```

With

```
dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"Family          Species
Family1         SpeciesA
Family1         SpeciesB
Family1         SpeciesC
Family2         SpeciesD
Family3         SpeciesE
Family4         SpeciesF")
```

you can shorten the code for the matrix multiplication to

```
as.matrix(dfa) %*% t(table(dat2)) # or 
tcrossprod(as.matrix(dfa), as.matrix(table(dat2)))
```

(tnx to @alexis_laz for the comment)
.
Another solution with base R:

```
d <- cbind(rowSums(dfa[1:3]), dfa[-(1:3)])
names(d) <- paste0("Family", 1:4)
d
```

Comment: The matrix product could be done as `as.matrix(dat1) %*% t(table(dat2))` or `tcrossprod(as.matrix(dat1), as.matrix(table(dat2)))`

Comment: @alexis_laz tnx for the comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: could you make a version for dozens of species/sites/families

Comment: @Ferroao Yes, if the dataframe `dat2` is given, the matrix multiplication can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another base R solution with a lookup table (named vector) and `rowSums`.

```
# get lookup table
lookup <- setNames(dfb$Species, dfb$Family)
# get corresponding column positions with match
colPos <- names(lookup)[match(names(dfa), lookup)]

# return data.frame with named columns
setNames(data.frame(lapply(unique(names(lookup)),
                           function(i) rowSums(dfa[i == colPos]))),
         unique(names(lookup)))
```

This returns

```
      Family1 Family2 Family3 Family4
Site1       5       6       2       5
Site2       5       6       2       5
Site3       5       6       2       5
Site4       5       6       2       5
```

In the second line, `match` is used to find the corresponding column positions. In the third line, `lapply` runs through the unique family names and applies `rowSums` to the columns that correspond to these names. This returns a list which is converted into a `data.frame` and given names with `setNames`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer 2 with data.table or dplyr:

```
data <- read.table(text="
sites      SpeciesA  SpeciesB  SpeciesC  SpeciesD  SpeciesE  SpeciesF
Site1     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site2     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site3     1          0        4        6          2        5
Site4     1          0        4        6          2        5" ,  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
famdf <- read.table(text="
Family          Species
Family1         SpeciesA
Family1         SpeciesB
Family1         SpeciesC
Family2         SpeciesD
Family3         SpeciesE
Family4         SpeciesF" ,  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#My answer 1 with data.table:
melted<-data.table::melt(data,id.vars="sites", variable.name= "Species")

data.table::dcast(
  setDT(merge(famdf, melted, by = "Species"))[,c("sites","Family","value")], 
  ... ~ Family,
    fun = sum,
  value.var = "value", 
)
#end
#My answer 2 with dplyr or data.table:
transpose<-function(df){
  n<-df[,1]
  df <- as.data.frame(t(df[,-1]))
  colnames(df) <- n
  df$id<-factor(row.names(df))
  return(df)
  }
data<-transpose(data)
data$fam<-fam$Family[match(data$id, fam$Species)]
data <- subset(data, select = -id )

#Sum option 1 data.table
library(data.table)
transpose(setDF(setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD,sum), by = .(fam)]))
#Sum option 2 dplyr
library(dplyr)
result<-as.data.frame(data %>%
  group_by(fam) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
)
transpose(result)
```