# Replacing column names from another dataframe with missing column names in R?

Tags: r, merge, matching, missing-data

I have two data-sets:

a. A data frame that looks like this:

```
        SpeciesA  SpeciesB  SpeciesC  SpeciesD  SpeciesE  SpeciesY SpeciesZ
Site1     1          0        4        6          2        5        2
Site2     1          0        4        6          2        5        3
Site3     1          0        4        6          2        5        4
Site4     1          0        4        6          2        5        5
```

(Note: The row values are NOT identical. This is just for the purpose of representation here)

b. Another data-set that looks like this:

```
Order          Species
Order1         SpeciesA
Order1         SpeciesB
Order2         SpeciesC
Order2         SpeciesD
Order3         SpeciesE
```

Notice that some species (eg. SpeciesZ, SpeciesY) does not have a corresponding "Order" in (b).

I want to match the Order column in data-set (2) to the corresponding Species in data-frame(1) and add up the values (if there are multiple species) under the same Order. When there is no corresponding Order for the species (eg.SpeciesY, SpeciesZ), I want to rename the column as NULL and then remove it (Note I need both the steps)

Pre-Final output

```
         Order1    Order1   Order3    NULL   NULL
Site1     1          10       2        5     2
Site2     1          10       2        5     3
Site3     1          10       2        5     4
Site4     1          10       2        5     5
```

Final output

```
         Order1      Order2    Order3   
Site1     1             10          2                
Site2     1             10          2                    
Site3     1             10          2                    
Site4     1             10          2
```

This is an extension of the question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437915/how-to-match-replace-and-sum-header-rows-from-another-dataset-in-r), which has code for the most part using `dplyr` or `melt`/`reshape` functions. However, I am finding it difficult to perform the same analysis for this as it would spit out an error saying that there are no corresponding values for some species

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create an index with `match`, `split` the subset of dataset using the `Order` column, loop through the `list` elements and get the `rowSums`

```
i1 <- match(colnames(df1), df2$Species, nomatch = 0)
data.frame(lapply(split.default(df1[i1], df2$Order[i1]), rowSums))
#      Order1 Order2 Order3
#Site1      1     10      2
#Site2      1     10      2
#Site3      1     10      2
#Site4      1     10      2
```

---

Or we can convert the first dataset to 'long' format, join with the second, grouped by columns, get the `sum` of the value column and reshape it back to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, "rn") %>%
      gather(Species, Val, -rn) %>% 
      left_join(., df2, by = "Species") %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      group_by(rn, Order) %>% 
      summarise(Val = sum(Val))  %>%
      spread(Order, Val)
```

Comment: I am not sure what match is doing, but when I run this, I see that i1 is taking values greater than the number of columns in df1. eg. I have i1 as a vector of (1,522,4 .. etc). That when I run df1[i1] it says undefined columns selected

Comment: The above comment is in reference to the Option(1) in code

Comment: I figured it out. I think there was a glitch on my end. Works well now!